# allegro5 C++ al_load_bitmap crashes program and refuses to work

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, allegro, allegro5

I am having a very strange problem with allegro5. I am trying to draw a bitmap with `al_load_bitmap`. When I tested it with an example program I took from the allegro wiki it worked great and displayed the bitmap. Unfortunately, once I started trying to make a program of my own, which very closely resembled the example program, the program crashed every time it encountered `al_load_bitmap`. I am trying to find out what is different between my program and the example program.

```
// The example program:
#include "allegro5/allegro.h"
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
#include "allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP  *image   = NULL;

    if(!al_init()) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to 
            initialize allegro!" NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
            return 0;
    }

    if(!al_init_image_addon()) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to      
            initialize al_init_image_addon!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
            return 0;
    }

    display = al_create_display(800,600);

    if(!display) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to 
            initialize display!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

            return 0;
    }

    image = al_load_bitmap("image.png");

    if(!image) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to load 
            image", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
            al_destroy_display(display);
        return 0;
    }

    al_draw_bitmap(image,200,200,0);

    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(2);

    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_bitmap(image);

    return 0;
}
```

My program:

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h"         

int main(void)
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = NULL;

    if(!al_init())                                      //initialize Allegro
        return -1;

    if(!al_init_image_addon()) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to 
            initialize al_init_image_addon!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

            return 0;
    }

    display = al_create_display(width, height);

    if(!display)                                        
        return -1;

    image = al_load_bitmap("orange.jpg");

    if(!image) {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to load     
            image!", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

            al_destroy_display(display);
        return 0;
    }

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0));

    al_draw_bitmap(image, 0, 0, 0);

    al_flip_display();

    al_rest(5);

    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_bitmap(image);                       //destroy our display object

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail about the error and the structure of your folder?

Comment: Use your debugger to step through your code and find the
error. If you still can't find it, post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the error output you are referring to as "crash".

Comment: Does your image load on other programs? I saw you checked for null pointer so the image is loading, so the issue might be the image format is not correct for Allegro

Comment: The folder for my project has the image in the main directory along with the file, for some reason this same thing is also happening for grabbing keyboard input